# ST_WITHIN function not working in POSTGIS

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, postgis, qgis

Why does the SQL query using spatial functions (e.g., ST_Within) return 'Location not found' instead of 'Location found' when providing latitude and longitude coordinates that are within a polygon stored in the PostgreSQL/PostGIS database?

```
@app.get('/polygons/<latitude>/<longitude>')
def verify_polygon(latitude, longitude):
    try:
        conn = connect_db()
        cur = conn.cursor()

        cur.execute(f'SELECT id_0 FROM public."polygons-c3" WHERE ST_Within(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint({longitude}, {latitude}), 4326), geom)')
        result = cur.fetchone()
        cur.close()
        conn.close()

        if result:
            return jsonify({'status': 'Location found', 'lote': result[0]}), 200
        else:
            return jsonify({'status': 'Location not found'}), 404
    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify({'error': str(e)}), 500
```

I expected "location found" because i get a point with Google maps that is on one of those polygons

Comment: Which version of postgis are you using?

Comment: That cannot be answered without knowing the data.

Comment: Are you sure your polygon is in 4326?

Comment: Check that both the point coordinates and the polygon are in the same coordinate reference system (CRS). In your query, you're setting the SRID of the point to 4326 (WGS 84), which is standard for latitude and longitude. Verify that the geom column of your polygons is also in this CRS. If not, you might need to transform one of them using ST_Transform.

Comment: `ST_Within()` wouldn't just return `false` if argument geometries' SRID didn't match, [it would throw an exception](https://dbfiddle.uk/4hQQNlLV).

Answer (score 0):

`ST_MakePoint()` accepts x+y, lon+lat, in that order.

> I get a point with Google maps that is on one of those polygons

My bet is you're comparing to coords straight from Google Maps r-click/URL, and those come in reverse order compared to that: y+x, lat+lon. For example, if you want to see near the North Pole it's

> https://www.google.com/maps/@85.0,1.0,4.0z

The parameter pair and what's shown if you right-click is 85° North, 1° West, (4.0 zoom). To get that location in PostGIS, you'd use the coordinates in the opposite order

```
ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(1,85),4326)
```

Make sure you're not passing latitude as longitude and vice versa. If you're accidentally flipping them, above becomes:

```
ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(85,1),4326)
```

Which is somewhere south of Sri Lanka (85° West, 1° North), near the equator (hot), not Greenland (cold). If you flip the coords back, your test points should fit your polygons fine.