# PostGIS: how to convert a point column into a type useable by ST_DWithin?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have the following query to try and get a total of places within the range of a provided point, comparing against my table of places. All places have a `geo` column, defined as `geo point default null`.

```
select
  count(*)
from
  places
where
  ST_DWithin(
    ST_GeomFromText(concat('POINT', geo::text), 4326),
    ST_GeomFromText('POINT(37.64903402157866, -83.84765625000001)', 4326),
    66 * 1609.34
  );
```

However, that returns:

```
parse error - invalid geometry
```

I tried casting to ::geometry, using other functions, but nothing really works. Here's how my data looks like:

```
select geo, geo::text, geo::geometry from places where geo is not null limit 10
```

returns:

```
{"x":-84.3871,"y":33.7485}
(-84.3871,33.7485)
01010000000612143FC61855C02B8716D9CEDF4040
```

Am I doing something wrong? Should I alter the table and store another column type? How do I not lose the existing data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your lon/lat order is flipped between what you're looking for and what you have in the table. You'll need to make sure which order is correct and flip back the target point or the data in the table. [PostGIS operates in x+y, lon+lat, while Google Maps is an example where you can find y+x, lat+lon.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77691940/5298879) Always check what you're dealing with.
2. `66 * 1609.34` seems like conversion from *miles* to *meters*, but since you're using type `geometry` in [4326](https://epsg.io/4326), [`STDWithin()`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html) will assume a *degree* to be your unit of measurement:

   > For geometry: The distance is specified in units defined by the spatial reference system of the geometries.

   Which means your target range exceeds the circumference of the globe, around 295 times.
3. Postgres' built-in [`point`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-geometric.html) is not the same type as [`geometry(Point)`](https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/geometries.html) from PostGIS extension. You'll need to cast or convert between them.
4. `STDWithin()` *can* measure in meters, but only if you give it `geography` types (or switch the CRS/SRID to meter-based), so that's another cast. It can also increase the precision at the cost of some performance, if you tell it to assume a spheroid, as it by default assumes the globe is a regular sphere.

[Demo at db<>fiddle:](https://dbfiddle.uk/cQYAxh_O)

```sql
create table places(id int generated by default as identity primary key, 
                    geo point,
                    comment text);
insert into places values 
  (1,point(-84.3871,33.7485),'your existing point'),
  (2,point(33.7485,-84.3871),'flipped lat/lon of existing point'),
  (3,point(37.64903402157866, -83.84765625000001),'target coords'),
  (4,point(-83.84765625000001, 37.64903402157866),'flipped target coords');
```

```sql
select
  count(*),array_agg(id::text||': '||comment)
from
  places
where
  ST_DWithin(
    geo::geometry::geography(Point,4326),
    ST_GeogFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(37.64903402157866 -83.84765625000001)'),
    66 * 1609.34, --66 miles
    true --measure over spheroid
  );
```

| count | array_agg |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | {"2: flipped lat/lon of existing point", "3: target coords"} |

Comment: That was very edifying, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

About everything is wrong here.

Type: you have postgres native `point` type, which is not usable by Postgis. You most likely want the `geometry(point)`

Conversion: Luckily, you can simply cast from point to geometry:

```sql
select point_column::geometry from mytable;
```

Coordinates order: In Postgis, coordinates are usually expressed as longitude first, then latitude. In you example, the column is in long-lat while the hard coded geometry is in lat-long.

Coordinate system: your data seems to be not projected. You could use a column specifying this, so cast using `point_column::geometry(point,4326)`.

Distances in 4326: DO NOT COMPUTE DISTANCES IN 4326. They are meaningless. A degree of longitude doesn't have the same ground length, in meters, as a degree of latitude.
Instead, you must use a suitable local projection that preserve distances or use the `geography` type instead, but be aware of the implication, especially over long distances.

Comment: So, columns should not be created in 4326?

ALTER TABLE sometable ADD COLUMN geog geography(POINT,4326);

Comment: For *`geometry`* columns, it's asking for problems. But all functions that support *`geography`* input, automatically switch to metric in that mode: [*For all spatial reference systems the units returned by measurement functions (e.g. ST_Distance, ST_Length, ST_Perimeter, ST_Area) and for the distance argument of ST_DWithin are in meters.*](https://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#PostGIS_Geography) so you can use any CRS. Problem is, not all functions accept *`geography`* type, and the extra precision costs performance. `use_spheroid` adds even more precision, even more slowly